# The differential operator : $\frac{1}{2}f''(x)-xf'(x) $

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I see the differential operator : $L(f) = \frac{1}{2}f''(x)-xf'(x)  $ poping frequently in my lesson yet I don't understand what it represent and why its useful ?

Normally it should have application in probability theory. If this operator has a name don't hesitate to tell me :)

Thank you !

Comment: Can you give examples? What contexts have you seen this?

Comment: @Winther When studying the entropy of a function with the mesure : $\mu = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-x^2}$ because this operator $L$ has the property that : $L(f) = \frac{1}{2\mu} (\mu f')'$

Comment: This is the infinitesimal generator of the $1$-dimensional ornstein-uhlenbeck process.